# unterminated string literal error in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, string-literals

The following code inside script tag is in a php while loop.

```
<?php 
//while loop starts here
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
     var url = "<?php echo $cfile;?>";
     var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer(
        '#jquery_jplayer_<?php echo $row_data['id'];?>',
        { '<?php echo $extension;?>' : url }, 
        { cssSelectorAncestor: '#cp_container_<?php echo $row_data['id'];?>', 
          swfPath: 'js', 
          wmode: 'window', 
          supplied: '<?php echo $extension;?>'
        });
     });
</script>
<?php
}
// while loop ends here
?>
```

So I am facing problem in the line -

```
var url = "<?php echo $cfile;?>";
```

where $cfile  is the url. And the value will be somewhat like this. (But as its in a loop, it will vary every time.)

```
$cfile= "http://www.domainname.com/foldername/wp-content/uploads/mp3 file name";
```

So the error is sometimes its showing-

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

var url = "http://www.
```

Please note that- I am not getting error every time, I get error on specific ids. 
So what is the issue & how I will solve this ?

I get the javascript part like this after php parsing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = "http://www.redfacilities.com/redfacilities/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/AlexisGraham.mp3";
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer('#jquery_jplayer_66',{ 'mp3' : url }, { cssSelectorAncestor: '#cp_container_66', swfPath: 'js', wmode: 'window', supplied: 'mp3'});
});
</script>
```

Comment: looks like you have a line break in the value `<?php echo $cfile;?>`

Comment: Show us the Javascript after PHP has parsed it.

Comment: @ArunPJohny No, I have checked the value in database, where I am getting error. But there is no line break. But as this is url, there  are slashes (/) and a colon (:) is sure there.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Edited my question to show you the javascript after PHP has parsed. Please check it.

Comment: Is the JS you added in the edit the same JS that the browser says the error occurs on? Because there's no error there (it looks fine, and copied and pasted into my browser it runs without error). Or is the error one of the other ones created in a different iteration of the PHP while?

Comment: @nnnnnn The thing is I am using pagination with 9 results in one page. And as you can see the error in the question, its not showing full value of "var url". So I am not able to trace that particular iteration where the error occurs.